Group the output of ps/top/htop by user?
I'm on Linux, with top and htop as well as ps.
How can I see a list of all users on the machine, together with the SUM of all their resource usage?  Something like this...



Username
Number of Processes
CPU%
Mem




user3
20
823%
75G


root
200
354%
24G


user1
99
123%
99G


user2
5
1%
2M


dbus
1
0%
5k



Do I need to script this with Python's psutil?
Thanks!

With systemd, start with something like systemd-cgtop to collect the cgroup-level task/cpu/memory counters from /sys/fs/cgroup. (It collects information from all cgroups; you want to limit it to only user-*.slice, so you'll most likely need to write your own tool that mimics it.)
This needs CPU accounting to be enabled in user.slice, but that's active by default in current versions. Note that 'tasks' also includes threads, not only whole processes, so large numbers are to be expected.
(Without systemd – it would still be the purpose of cgroups to provide this kind of accounting, so I'd find some way to move user sessions into cgroups regardless, e.g. using libcgroup-pam.)
